# Have installed chrome on Ubuntu. However cannot find where to run it

Tags: google-chrome

The installer says chrome has been installed.  It does not show up in Software Center.

Comment: Click on the top left button with the Ubuntu logo and type in chrome. And press the chrome icon.

Comment: Google Chrome is not available in the Software Center, so it doesn't show up in the Software Center.

Comment: How did you install Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I can access Chrome.  Ubuntu is a very nice distro.

Answer (score 39):

type the command below to locate chrome

```
whereis google-chrome
```

and execute `/usr/bin/google-chrome` command to run chrome

Comment: Click Windows button and type in **chrome**, if you installed chrome properly the chrome will shows up. Simply  you can run chrome by clicking the icon.